# python and twisted proxy, how to gunzip on the fly?

Tags: python, proxy, gzip, twisted

how may i gunzip and process response part when using twistedmatrix `ProxyClient`?

i need to examine text or javascript and ajax query/answer. Is it that I should use the `handleResponseEnd`?

I think it was inside the handleResponsePart, but it looks like I have misunderstood a point or something, here is my skeleton code:

```
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.web import http, proxy

class ProxyClient(proxy.ProxyClient):
    """Mange returned header, content here.

    Use `self.father` methods to modify request directly.
    """
    def handleHeader(self, key, value):
            # change response header here
            log.msg("Header: %s: %s" % (key, value))
            proxy.ProxyClient.handleHeader(self, key, value)

    def handleResponsePart(self, buffer):
    # this part below do not work, 
    # looks like @ this moment i do not have 'Content-Encoding' or 'Content-Type'
    # what am i misunderstading?
            cEncoding = self.father.getAllHeaders().get('Content-Encoding', '')
            cType = self.father.getAllHeaders().get('Content-Type', '')
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Content-Encoding', cEncoding
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Content-Type', cType
            if ('text' in cType.lower() or 'javascript' in cType.lower()) and 'gzip' in cEncoding.lower():

                buf = StringIO(buffer)
                s = gzip.GzipFile(mode="rb", fileobj=buf)
                content = s.read(len(buffer))

                # here process content as it should be gunziped

    proxy.ProxyClient.handleResponsePart(self, buffer)

class ProxyClientFactory(proxy.ProxyClientFactory):
    protocol = ProxyClient

class ProxyRequest(proxy.ProxyRequest):
    protocols = dict(http=ProxyClientFactory)

class Proxy(proxy.Proxy):
    requestFactory = ProxyRequest

class ProxyFactory(http.HTTPFactory):
    protocol = Proxy
```

from my logging i have:

```
2013-06-11 14:07:33+0200 [ProxyClient,client] Header: Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2013 12:07:25 GMT
2013-06-11 14:07:33+0200 [ProxyClient,client] Header: Server: Apache
...
2013-06-11 14:07:33+0200 [ProxyClient,client] Header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
...
2013-06-11 14:07:33+0200 [ProxyClient,client] Header: Content-Encoding: gzip
...
2013-06-11 14:07:33+0200 [ProxyClient,client] Header: Connection: close
```

thus i should have the two conditions ok! what am i missing please?

also even if i am not interested by this second way, that is to remove the accept for the request, like this, is it possible to do:
(btw it looks like it does not work or that the tested webservers do not care of the fact that we do not want to receive gzip-ed content)

```
class ProxyRequest(proxy.ProxyRequest):
    protocols = dict(http=ProxyClientFactory)

    def process(self):
        # removing the accept so that we do not tell "i'm ok with gzip encoded content" and should receive only not gzip-ed
        self.requestHeaders.removeHeader('accept')
        self.requestHeaders.removeHeader('accept-encoding')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to collect chunks of data into StringIO buffer in `handleResponsePart`, and then decode with GzipFile in `handleResponseEnd`.